# Git save raw files between commits

Tags: git, difference, repo

I wanna save/export the files different between two selected commits. The following command show me the modified files...

```
$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r bd61ad98
index.html
javascript/application.js
javascript/ie6.js
```

but there is a way to export them, preserving the file structure?
I need save only the modified files in web server instead of upload the whole project.

Comment: you can write out the output to a txt file with command line

Comment: @unixmiah but whats happens if I have binary file too, an image for example? Also... can I preserve directory structure using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the seed for a small shell script (save it in a file and make the file executable). It is not a complete script. You need to check if `$1` is provided in the command line and abort with an error message otherwise (or the rest of the script will fail with misleading error messages). It needs to work no matter where it is located and from where it is called (it works now only if your current directory is the project directory). It needs to deal with deleted files somehow (is they returned by the `git diff-tree` command?)

```
#!/bin/bash

commit=$1            # get the commit hash from the command line (the first argument)
dest='/tmp'          # path to your destination directory (change it to match your setup)

# Cleanup on the destination directory
rm -rf $dest
mkdir $dest

# Copy the modified files
for i in $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit); do
  cp --parents $i $dest/
done
```

Comment: Where can I put this, in git terminal or I need create a script?

Comment: I guess you want to do the same operation again and again and not only once. A file is the best place for it.

Comment: you can put all that in an .sh file. make sure you run chmod a+x on the .sh file so its executable to run; for example project-diff.sh. then go in the terminal and issue sh ./project-diff.sh or sh project-diff.sh

Comment: Turned the code into a small shell script, added some explains about what it **does not** do.

Answer (score 1):

See [git archive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html).

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit \
| xargs git archive -o changedfiles.tgz --
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r bd61ad98 | git archive --format zip --output "proj-diff.zip" master -0
```

-0 arg is for uncompressed archive; i haven't tested it out but this should work